# How to convert a string to a list if the string has wild characters for a group of characters like [] or {}, ()

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

I have a string of this sort

```
s = 'a,s,[c,f],[f,t]'
```

I want to convert this to a list

```
S = ['a','s',['c','f'],['f','t']]
```

I tried using `strip()`

```
d = s.strip('][').split(',')
```

But it is not giving me the desired output:

```
output = ['a', 's', '[c', 'f]', '[f', 't']
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-python/), having first enclosed each element in quotes:

```
>>> qs = re.sub(r'(\w+)', r'"\1"', s)  # add quotes
>>> ast.literal_eval('[' + qs + ']')   # enclose in brackets & safely eval
['a', 's', ['c', 'f'], ['f', 't']]
```

You may need to tweak the regex if your elements can contain non-word characters.

This only works if your input string follows Python expression syntax or is sufficiently close to be mechanically converted to Python syntax (as we did above by adding quotes and brackets).  If this assumption does not hold, you might need to look into using a [parsing library](https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-python/).  (You could also hand-code a recursive descent parser, but that'll probably be more work to do correctly than just using a parsing library.)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to `ast.literal_eval` you can use the `json` package with more or less the same restrictions of NPE's answer:

```
import re
import json

qs = re.sub(r'(\w+)', r'"\1"', s)  # add quotes
ls = json.loads('[' + qs + ']')
print(ls)         
# ['a', 's', ['c', 'f'], ['f', 't']]
```